# Can particles running in a loop go on-shell and does this create a "resonant" effect?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, resonance

Are there any Loop diagrams, where we need to consider the internal propagator with a additional $i\Gamma m$ in the denominator to get a finite result (apart from adding counterterms).
If yes does this create a resonance effect such as for an s-channel resonance or is the pole smoothed out by the integration of the loop momementa? Can we expect the loop function to gain some enhancement at a particular energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When internal states happen to be on-shell, this means that they could, in principle, be the final states of the scattering process. The imaginary part of the amplitude, mentioned by @CStarAlgebra is one way to see it. In terms of the "pedestrian" perturbation theory it means that the denominators in the perturbation series have to be integrated through the zero of their real parts, where only their imaginary part contributes.

**Example**
[This article](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.80.035416) presents an example from the condensed matter (more precisely from the field of mesoscopic): here one studied tunnelung through a quantum dot - a system of discrete levels with strong local Coulomb interaction - embedded in an Aharonov-Bohm geometry. When driven out of equilibrium, the on-shell scattering processes produced contributions breaking the phase rigidity normally expected in such systems.

Comment: Ok that makes sense to me. But my question is if we integrate over loop momenta with poles do we not get an enhancement for the real part in addition (due to the pole) to the non-vanishing imaginary part?

Comment: @krabbypatty It depends on the situation: in the situation in the cited article, one can assume a *broadband limit*, then the real part is something like the principal value of the integral over $1/\omega$, so it is zero. But generally speaking you may get a finite or perhaps even a diverging contribution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes an internal particle in a loop can go on shell. This is exactly when such an amplitude develops an imaginary part.